# Context Api - Reducer - Typescript Error (This expression is not callable.)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYg10.png)

I create context api with typescript. But I have some error about dispatch method when i use it other component to make changes with reducer. How can I solve this 'This expression is not callable.' onthe dispatch method.

The error is that; [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5eX3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `as` cast is typed wrongly (and possibly shouldn't be there anyway). The current one, `Array<string | React.Dispatch>`, defines an arbitrary length array of elements that can be either type.

It should be typed as `[string, React.Dispatch]` or you could try not casting it at all - TypeScript infers types rather well and your `as` is basically overriding its inferrence.

Comment: For the future, also please include code as text and not pictures.